# Python TelegramBot running a function in job_queue.run_repeating

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, job-queue

I want to send a message to the person at certain intervals, there is no problem when the code in check_who_likes works alone, but when I make it a function and try to run it with job_queue, I get an error.

```
async def check_who_likes(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    try:
        conn = connection_pool.get_connection()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        user_id = update.message.from_user.id
        cursor.execute("SELECT LikeUserID FROM Likes WHERE LikedUserID = %s", (user_id,))
        likes = cursor.fetchall()
        like_ids = [like[0] for like in likes]
        like_ids_str = ', '.join(map(str, like_ids))
        sql_query = f"SELECT UserName FROM Users WHERE PersonID IN ({like_ids_str})"
        cursor.execute(sql_query)
        users = cursor.fetchall()
        liked_users_text = ", ".join(str(user[0]) for user in users)
        await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id,
                                       text=f"{len(likes)} kişi sizi beğendi.Bakmak istermisin?\n\n\n1.Göster.\n2.Artık aramıyorum.")

    except Exception as e:
        pass
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        if update.message.text == "1":
            return SHOW_WHO_LIKES
async def matching(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    context.job_queue.run_repeating(check_who_likes, interval=1, first=0)
```

**Error:

No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\wamp64\www\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext_jobqueue.py", line 898, in _run
await self.callback(context)
TypeError: check_who_likes() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'**

Comment: I see that you `return SHOW_WHO_LIKES` from your `check_who_likes` callback, which makes the improession that you aim to change the state of a `ConversationHandler` here. Note that this won't work as you schedule this callback as a job. Instead, the `matching` callback would have to return that state.

Comment: the return there is left over before it was turned into a function, so it does not have much importance, my goal now is to run a process that I have turned into a function continuously in certain regions with job_queue.

Answer (score 1):

Your callback is invalid

From [docs](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.6/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html#telegram.ext.JobQueue.run_repeating) the Callback signature should be

```
async def callback(context: CallbackContext)
```

but your code is

```
async def check_who_likes(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
```

First you need change signature of `check_who_likes` to correct signature

```
async def check_who_likes(context: CallbackContext, update: Update):
```

Next, if you want other arguments, there are 2 options, you could try:

###### <strike>Option 1: pass more kwargs by using [`job_kwargs`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.6/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html#telegram.ext.JobQueue.run_repeating.params.job_kwargs) in `JobQueue.run_repeating`</strike> **WRONG OPTION**

```
async def matching(context: CallbackContext):
    context.job_queue.run_repeating(check_who_likes, interval=1, first=0, job_kwargs=dict(update=update))
```

###### Option 2: using `functools.partial` function

```
from functools import partial

async def matching(context: CallbackContext):
    context.job_queue.run_repeating(partial(check_who_likes, update=update), interval=1, first=0)
```

Comment: `job_kwargs` do not add an additional argument to the callback function. The `job_kwargs` argument is there to pass additional information to the `apscheduler` library, which does the scheduling of the jobs. Note that there is the argument `data` of `JobQueue.run_*` which is designed specifically to pass additional information into the job callback.

Comment: I see, i will remove option 1